# how to get anyType value using jaxb?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an xml that looks like this:

```
<Root>
   <tag1>4</tag1>
   <tag2>aa</tag2>
   <tag3 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">bla bla bla</anyType>
      <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">3</anyType>
   </tag3>
</Root>
```

the object generated by xjc is:

```
public class Root {
  @XmlElement(name="tag1")
  protected short tag1;

  @XmlElement(name="tag2")
  protected String tag2;

  @XmlElement(name="tag3")
  protected Object tag3;
}
```

when i unmarshal the xml i get some kind of an xml element in tag3.
I need something generic to get the values in tag3 into a list.

any ideas?

thanks.

Comment: Can you change to XML a la wrap the element list in sequence tags?

Comment: no. the xml is predefined and i cant change it. i can change the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer truns out to be simple. 
I just change

```
  @XmlElement(name="tag3")
  protected Object tag3;
```

to:

```
 @XmlWrapper(name = "tag3")
 @XmlElements(@XmlElement(name="anyType"))
  protected List<Object> list;
```

my problem was with the object genertaed by xjc.

Answer (score 0):

Create class AnyType. And decalre tag3 as array of AnyType

```
 @XmlElement(name="tag3")
 protected AnyType[] tag3;
```

Comment: i created the class but when i unmarshal the value of the member in AnyType is null. BTW - notice that tag3 is of an xml struct by itself.